# Does a child need a father and a mother?

Tags: children, sexuality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any scientific evidence regarding measurable adverse effects (if any) of child rearing by homosexual human couples?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2153/is-there-any-scientific-evidence-regarding-measurable-adverse-effects-if-any-o)

Every time someone brings up same sex couples and adoption, someone has to mention "but children need a dad and a mom". Are there any studies that proof or disproof this statement?

Comment: While not *literally* the same, it shares pretty much the same answer as the dupe.

Comment: I didn't find the other question, but it does answers my question. So thanks!

Comment: does a child need money? C'mon guys. Many people are angry with me for showing the obvious that kids need tons of money to raise and poor dad shouldn't breed. Looks like it's not obvious enough. I asked in sceptic forum and the question is closed.